# What is the default location in which require_once looks out?

Tags: php, require

I just took a look after how to send mail via google smtp.

PEAR appeared as the appropriate library to do the job.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page) code snippet there is a

```
require_once "Mail.php";
```

Where does this file resides? Does __autoload() function make some trick? If i change it to fit my classes' folder path I might broke the magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get in the habit of checking [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) before asking questions like this here. It covers this:

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

`__autoload()` is a separate concept from `include` and/or `require`. It is a function which is automatically called when you try to use a class which has not yet been defined. It is a function you write yourself, to define your own algorithm for determining what files you need to `include`, based on your project's file structure.

You should also avoid using `__autoload()` in your code, since there can be only one `__autoload()` function defined. Instead, you should use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead. This function takes the name of other functions and adds it to a list of functions that, when an unknown class is invoked, will each be called until one of them finds the file which defines the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is looked in the include path http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.include-path